# Trigger to update grandchild records

Tags: relationships

How do I update a grandchild's field if there is a change in grandparent field? I know I have to write a trigger because its cross object

I can access the immediate child record of **parent** which is **child**

```
 List<parent__c> fbr = [SELECT Name , 
                           (SELECT Id , Name, CreatedDate FROM child__r) 
                           FROM parent__c];
```

Any reference will be helpful. Thanks

Comment: this was just an example which is working..i want to know how to access a grandchild

Comment: I'm not sure about a direct way. You can populate a `Set` with child ids and query for grandchildren then. For doing manipulations it'll be easy if you use `Map`s

Comment: Simple parente->child->grandchild changes can relativly easily be done with formula fields, have you considered that ? Providing more detail of what you're trying to do and how your data model looks like will result in better answers. Help us help you.

Comment: Thanks @SamuelDeRycke. I will update the question with an example. It is indeed too broad.

Comment: I'm actually not the person who did the close vote, i think your question is fine, just a bit rough to understand :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get your grandchilderen with a subselect in the SOQL where clause.

**In words:**

Select the grandchilderend who's parent's parent is one of the grandparents you have.

**In code:**

```
//example=  account (parent) -> testobject__c -> testChildObject__c (grandchild)

    List<Account> accs = trigger.New;  //list of grandparents that have been changed
    list<testChildObject__c> lst = [SELECT Id,name, testobject__c 
                                    FROM testChildObject__c 
                                    WHERE testObject__c In (SELECT id 
                                                            FROM testObject__C 
                                                            WHERE Account_lookup__c in:accs
                                                            )
                                  ];
```

- testChildObject__c object has a lookup to the testobject__c: field testObject__c
- testobject__c object has a looup to account:  field  Account_lookup__c

Answer (score 0):

"In each specified relationship, only one level of parent-to-child relationship can be specified in a query. For example, if the FROM clause specifies Account, the SELECT clause can only specify the Contact or other objects at that level. It could not specify a child object of Contact." (http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/dbcom_soql_sosl/Content/sforce_api_calls_soql_relationships.htm)

One option would be to rephrase the query, if you can, into a select from the Grandchild object, as you can reference 5 levels of parents upwards.
e.g.

```
select child__r.parent__r.name, name from grandchild__c where ....
```